# Get highest score and number of wins

Tags: mysql, select, join

[image: Database]

Here is my database. Every photo have some points and is taken by specific user. Each photo is also assigned to the event. I want to find a picture with the highest number of points for each event. I also want to count how many events you won ( eg. For the user with id = 10 ). Could you please help me? I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: i'm  thinking you don't need all the tables that you've shown. It looks like \`points\` and \`photos\` are both relationships between \`events\` and \`users\`. There doesn't appear to be a direct relationship between \`photos\` and \`points\`.

Comment: Wrong picture. Excuse me. Corrected .

Comment: Excuse me, but, what field of the table "points" have the number of points (or in what table that information is saved)?

Comment: You are asking for two different queries: one for a list of events with the highest scoring photo for that event (but what if there's a tie?); the other for a user with the number of events that user won.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two queries to achieve what you need:

> picture with the highest number of points for each event.

```
SELECT      e.id event_id,
            e.name event_name, 
            ph.id photo_id,
            ph.title photo_title,
            u.id user_id,
            u.login user_login,
            COUNT(*) points
FROM        events e
INNER JOIN  photos ph
        ON  ph.event_id = e.id
        AND ph.id = (
              SELECT      ph.id
              FROM        photos ph
              INNER JOIN  points p 
                       ON p.photo_id = ph.id
              WHERE       ph.event_id = e.id
              GROUP BY    ph.id
              ORDER BY    COUNT(*) DESC
              LIMIT       1
            )
-- optional if you need to know the points            
INNER JOIN  points p 
         ON p.photo_id = ph.id
-- optional if you need to know the owner of the photo
INNER JOIN  users u
         ON u.id = ph.user_id
GROUP BY    e.id,
            e.name,
            ph.id,
            ph.title
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d75/2).

> count how many events you won

```
SELECT      u.id user_id,
            u.login user_login,
            COUNT(distinct e.id) events_won
FROM        events e
INNER JOIN  photos ph
        ON  ph.event_id = e.id
        AND ph.id = (
              SELECT      ph.id
              FROM        photos ph
              INNER JOIN  points p 
                       ON p.photo_id = ph.id
              WHERE       ph.event_id = e.id
              GROUP BY    ph.id
              ORDER BY    COUNT(*) DESC
              LIMIT       1
            )
INNER JOIN  users u
         ON u.id = ph.user_id
GROUP BY    u.id,
            u.login
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d75/3)